# Link and open specific tab with window.location.hash

Tags: jquery, function, hash, tabs

I have the following code that opens and closes tabs when clicked upon. 
Would like an ahref link to open a tab (through window.location.hash), but I cannot make it happen.
Any ideas on how to open a specific tab when linked to a hash variable?

The code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Initialize to closed
jQuery('.wp-super-faq-answer').hide();  

// If a closed question is clicked
jQuery('.wp-super-faq-question-closed').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var wp_super_faq_id = '#' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + '-answer';
    jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass('wp-super-faq-question-open');
    jQuery(wp_super_faq_id + ' .wp-super-faq-triangle').html('&#9660;');
    jQuery('.wp-super-faq-answer' + wp_super_faq_id).slideDown();

});


// If an open question is clicked
jQuery('.wp-super-faq-question-open').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var wp_super_faq_id = '#' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + '-answer';
    jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass('wp-super-faq-question-closed');
    jQuery(wp_super_faq_id + ' .wp-super-faq-triangle').html('&#9654;');
    jQuery('.wp-super-faq-answer' + wp_super_faq_id).slideUp();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event listener on hashchange to fire the method needed.

```
$(window).on("hashchange",function() {
   ...
});
```

further please use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).